# Yield async execution javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, call, asynccallback

I want to illustrate the problem with code:

```
var async1 = f1(params, cb);
var async2 = f2(params, cb);
```

Right now I can call async1 through a waterfall async process like it follows:

```
async.waterfall([
 function(cb){

   async1(params, cb);
   async2(params, cb);

},
//default process
function(result, cb){
    //some code here and then

    cb(null, result);
}
], done);
```

My question is how can I wait for `async1` to complete the `done` callback so I can call `async2`. Both task needs to run the default process and the done callback.

If there a way/design pattern where I can run `async1` and after it is completed I can run `async2` within the same waterfall async function? Both async functions are required to complete the default process and the done callback.

Thanks.

Comment: Look up [`await` (ES7 draft)](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-primer-on-es7-async-functions--cms-22367) or [_Promises_ (ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: how about `async.series`

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using callback functions. Consider the following:

```
// When you're defining this function, give it a callback parameter
function async1(params, cb, callback){
    ...
    // Call the callback function when this process is complete
    callback();
}

...

// Then call your functions something like this
async1(params, cb, function(){
    async2(params, cb);
});
```

This can also be accomplished with the use of [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). Promises are the same idea, just done a little differently.